# Syntax Error with rails unexpected ')'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Hi there I want to add a destroy action in post#show view I think I have creates the environment but when I place this code with a condition I have a message error.

```
<% if @user.comment == current_user %> 
  <% link_to @post_comment_path(post_id: @post.id, id: comment.id), method:    :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %> 
  <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> 
<% end %>
 <% end %>
```

I created a partial in post show#view which names _comments.html.erb

here it is

```
<p class="text-center">Poster un commentaire</p>
      <%= simple_form_for [post, post.comments.new] do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
        <%= f.input :content, label: "Commentaire"%>
        <%= f.submit "Envoyer", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
```

and it render like that `<%= render 'comments' %>`

and above the partial (in post show#view) I do an iteration like that

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
   <li>
      <p><% comment.content %></p>
   <% end %>
   </li>
</ul>
```

But nothing appears when I create a new message, I don't userstand why.

I give your more code details

**post.rb**

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

**comment.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

The route is:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :categories
  resources :comments
end
```

Comments controller is

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_post

def create
  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id

  if @comment.save
    flash[:success] = "You commented the hell out of that post!"
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:alert] = "There is a problem with your comment"
    render root_path
  end
end

def destroy
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

  @comment.destroy
  flash[:success] = "Comment deleted :("
  redirect_to root_path
end

private

def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
end

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :post_id, :user_id)
end
end
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: `<% if @user.comment == current_user %>` How you are comparing this ? `@user.comment` returns the comment object and `current_user` is an user object.

Comment: `<% link_to @post_comment_path(post_id: @post.id, id: comment.id), method:    :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>`   should be `<% link_to post_comment_path(post_id: @post.id, id: comment.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>`

Comment: I have to think @user.comment is the user who create the comment and is actually current_user as connected. Yes there is an error with that.

Comment: I tried what you did but there an error 'undefined local variable or method `comment' for #<#<Class:0x007fb154c64168>:0x007fb14d1e7b60>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link_to erb code needs an equals sign for it to actually display

```
<%= link_to post_comment_path(post_id: @post.id, id: comment.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do
```

Comment: I have the error : `undefined local variable or method `comment'`

Comment: should probably be @comment.id

Comment: it works I put destroy method in the iteration `<ul class="list-unstyled">
                <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
                <li>

                    <p><%= comment.content %></p>
                </li>

                <%= link_to post_comment_path(post_id: @post.id, id: comment.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>
                      <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
              </ul>`